# MySQL и Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2017

Пытаюсь подружить MySql и Visual Studio 2017 (написать элементарную примитивную программу вывода данных из БД). Установил MYSQL for Visual Studio, Connector/Net 6.9.10.
Настройил новое соединение, в Server Explorer базы данных созданные в MYSQL отображаются, данные отображаются, SQL запросы из Visual Studio обрабатываются.
Пробовал написать программу, дорбавил в проект при помощи NUget MySql.Data.Entity, MySql.Data. Пытался написать несколько примеров из
https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/23.php 
или 
http://lvasquez.github.io/2014/11/18/EntityFramework-MySql/
или
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-MySql-Database-with-MySql-Connector-in-ASPNet-MVC-Razor-Tutorial-with-example.aspx
или
http://www.bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-mysql.html

При попытке выполнить любой из предыдущих примеров - ошибка возникает одна и та же при выполнении программы-
System.TypeLoadException: "Правила безопасности наследования нарушены типом: 
"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices". Производные типы должны либо 
соответствовать по доступности в контексте безопасности базовому типу, либо 
быть менее доступными."

Например из  примера https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/23.php

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MobileContext : DbContext
{
    public MobileContext(): base("conn")
    { }
        //Возникает ошибка System.TypeLoadException: "Правила безопасности наследования нарушены типом: 
//"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices". Производные типы должны либо 
//соответствовать по доступности в контексте безопасности базовому типу, либо 
//быть менее доступными."

    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема?

Comment: такие не частые ошибки в англоязычном сегменте искать следует, вот аналоичные вопросы к примеру. [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47227495/1216425), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46944413/1216425) во всех подобных вопросах так или иначе решением является даунгрейд чего-либо (mysql.data.enitty коннектера или чего там на версии 6.9 или 6.8)

Answer (score 2):

Тоже с этим мучался - [ЗДЕСЬ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227495/inheritance-security-rules-violated-by-type-mysql-data-entity-mysqlefconfigura) нашел свой ответ.

**Мои инструкции (по опыту):**
Убедитесь, что удалены из проекта ранее установленные версии MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity, EntityFramework. И удалите все ссылки из Web.config на MySql.

установил из NuGet консоли в VS2017 **(ВЕРСИЯ 6.8.8!!!)**:

```
Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version 6.8.8
```

Мой файл контекста доступа к базе:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ANF_Test_0001.Models
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class MyDBContext : DbContext
    {

        public MyDBContext() : base("conn"){ }

        public DbSet<Table1> Table1s { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>();
        }

    }

}
```

Далее по книге :)